# MySQL UNION With Like and <

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am trying to create a UNION that

Create a union to provide the results of faculty who has an ID in the 100s and their salary is less than 65,000.

```
faculty
facID   name    salary
320 Laura Kassler   50000
125 Charity Burbage 62000
500 Pomona Sprout   61000
100 Minerva McGonagall  85000
185 Severus Snape   70000
200 Rubeus Hagrid   50000
```

This is my code:

```
select name, facID, salary
from faculty
where salary < '65000'
UNION
select name, facID, salary
from faculty
where facID like '1%';
```

The result:

```
+--------------------+-------+--------+
| name               | facID | salary |
+--------------------+-------+--------+
| Minerva McGonagall |   100 |  85000 |
| Charity Burbage    |   125 |  62000 |
| Severus Snape      |   185 |  70000 |
| Rubeus Hagrid      |   200 |  50000 |
| Laura Kassler      |   320 |  50000 |
| Pomona Sprout      |   500 |  61000 |
+--------------------+-------+--------+
```

The answer is supposed to be Charity Burbage facID 125 and a salary of 62000.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `AND` makes so much more sense than `UNION`.

Comment: A union just runs two queries and returns their data as one result set. Your union is working properly. The problem is that a union is not the right thing to use to get the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, facID, salary
from faculty
where salary < '65000'
and facID like '1%'
order by facID;
```

Comment: I had it that way and spoke to the teacher that wrote the question. He told me that I must use the word UNION and that there was only one result. So I am more confused than ever.

Comment: UNION only has sense if the question was something similar to: Provide the results of faculty who has an ID=100  `PLUS` all that their salary is less than 65000, but even then you can change UNION by OR.

Answer (score 0):

Then try returning nothing from the result of the second select statement.

```
    select name, facID, salary
    from faculty
    where salary < '65000' AND facID like '1%'
    UNION
    select name, facID, salary
    from faculty
    where 1 <> 1
    Order by facID
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. The last part of your code "where 1 <> 1" was not in any of my books. I will remember that now.

Comment: @Ashley there's a reason it isn't in any of your books.  Your teacher's requirement to use `UNION` doesn't make any sense for the problem listed in your question.

Comment: I totally agree that it doesn't make sense on the question. But the answer worked for the desired results.